# Flex canvas resizing

Tags: apache-flex, browser, canvas, components, resize

I have a certain behavior that i want from my screen to implement in Flex.
My screen is devided to 2 areas: Navigator pane and content pane.(from left to right)
When I shrink the browser, i want the content-pane show scroll bars and the components stay the same size originally.
When I expand the browser to right(like in wide screen), i want that components (like DataGrid) will 
expand to right.
How can i do it? Is it done with minWidth and minHeight?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the easiest way to do stuff like this is to override either the measure function or the updateDisplayList function and set the sizes manually. Sometimes min/max sizes work, sometimes they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I replaced the mx:Canvas with mx:Panel and this works better. as i expect.
Height and Width are with percentage representation. There is also minWidth, minHeight 
definitions on the panel. once the frame goes under minWidth or minHeight propeties, scrollbars are opened.

important NOTE: if you compile with ANT (mxmlc), you may used another config file (i.e. other than the one Flash Builder uses).
note that each one has different parameters. also note that each one of them may generate a different .html file that embedds the swf.(according to the html template) (for example width parameter)